# Unable to handle error from server side of my Application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am using mongodb query in Exress js but unable to handle any error there like i have a query

```
db.collection('prowd').deleteOne({_id: ObjectID( id)}, (err, result) => {
    if (err){return console.log(err)}
    else res.send(result)
  })
```

even though there isnt any 'prowd' collection in my db why am i not seeing any error in console ?

from the react side when i make a req to this api i get success message

```
 onDeleteProduct(id) {
    axios
      .post("/delete-product", {
        id
      })
      .then(() => {
        Swal.fire({
          icon: "success",
          title: "Product Deleted Successfully !",
          showConfirmButton: false,
          timer: 1500
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        Swal.fire({
          icon: "success",
          title: "Task failed !",
          showConfirmButton: false,
          timer: 1500
        });
      });
  }
```

for the query i have written i should get meesage of

> Task failed

Comment: replace console.log with response

Comment: sorry @LawrenceCherone didnt work and coudnt understand either :(

Comment: `catch` is for errors, you need to trigger it, in your server-side code your only responding on successfulness `res.send`, you need to respond with a status code, maybe 422 or in the 500 range, then catch is fired.. https://runkit.com/lcherone/5e7120e0af9c290013bd06d7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is executed successfully without any record deleted. Therefore we don't have an error, that means `err == null`, but you can see `result.result.n` will be `0`, which means ***the number of affected records***

You can see this code:

```js
db.collection('prowd').deleteOne({ _id: ObjectID(id) }, (err, result) => {
    if (err) { return console.log(err) }
    console.log(result.result.n); // ==> that is 0 if not exist any record
})
```

About why we don't have any collection or even a database, but Mongo still executes successfully, that is Mongo don't require constraints about the existence of collection or database, it's NoSQL.

Thank for reading :D